# web element exists in page, text content but not scraped by selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, screen-scraping

I'm tryng to scrape the (number of last page) by XPATH, the problem is when i search by xpath in developer i find the element and its text. However, when scraping by selenium, it returns empty string ''.

```
url = 'https://www.audible.com/search
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options = options)
driver.get(url)
all_pages =   WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//ul[contains(@class,"pagingElements ")]/li')))

last_page = all_pages[-2]
int (last_page.get_attribute('textContent'))`
```

Comment: First, you have to scroll down your page, and pagination is visible, then only selenium locate the element. please try this and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should scroll down, using `ActionChains` and only then, when pagination is rendered, get needed element attribute.
Also it's better to get `innerText` of a than `textContent` of li as far as textContent contain line separators.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = 'https://www.audible.com/search'
driver.get(url)
footer = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'ui-it-footer-wrapper')))
actionChains.move_to_element(footer).perform()
all_pages = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//ul[contains(@class,"pagingElements ")]//a')))

last_page_attrubute = all_pages[-2].get_attribute('innerText')
```